# Connecting cell selection to presenting segue (show) - swift

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uicollectionview

I have as storyboard in iOS with a navigation controller and a few view controllers. The segues that I use with the navigation buttons work just fine, it's connected to the button action through the interface builder and goes through. Now I have a view controller with a view collection and would like for the next view to present itself upon tapping one of the cells. I have connected the cell to the next view controller and the navigation bars popped up as they should in the next view controller and presenting segues show that "show" is connected to "cell selection". The view controller with the collection has didSelectItemAtIndexPath: implemented so is it something I should add in the implementation of that action for it to work or am not doing something right with the interface builder?

Comment: Try to add 
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifer", sender: self)
inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Can you vote my comment? :) thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments. Calling  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifer", sender: self) fixed it.